# Dont dim desktop when asking password for administrative changes

Tags: login-screen

Is there an option to turn off dimming the desktop when asking/prompting the password
for administrative tasks? Like in Windows User Account Control.

It hurts my eyes everytime it dims my desktop instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Open Configuration Editor (gconf-editor) and navigate to /apps/gksu. Now, tick off the box that says 'Disable Grab'. Alternatively, you could run

```
gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/gksu/disable-grab "True"
```

in a terminal.

Comment: That works, although it makes the dialog appear in an ugly transparent window here: http://img.xrmb2.net/images/782507.png